# Solve $x,y$ given $1+x^2+2x\sin(\arccos y)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse

I have to solve $x,y$ given-

> $$1+x^2+2x\sin(\arccos y)=0$$

My attempt:

$$1+x^2+2x\sin(\arcsin \sqrt{1-y^2})=0$$ (Is this step valid? Can I convert arccos to arcsin like this?)

$$\implies1+x^2+2x\sqrt{1-y^2}=0$$

Now,I can't procced further. What to do next?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:$$\sin(\arccos(y))=-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ and $$|\sin(x)|\le 1$$

Comment: Okay... so, $x$ must be $=1$ right?

Comment: But, $x=-1$ it should be... how should I know if $x=1$ or $x=-1$? Should I take both values and see which one satisfies?

Comment: You will get $$x^2+1\le |x|$$ so $x=-1$ is also possible.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $2$ in front of $|x|$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The discriminant is $$(2\sqrt{1-y^2})^2-4\cdot1\cdot1=-4y^2$$

$$x=\dfrac{-2\sqrt{1-y^2}\pm2iy}2$$

$\implies$ for real $x,$

$y$ must be $0$

Comment: (+1) This was nice ;-) and left in a more dilemma about which answer I should accept ...

Answer (score 1):

Solving for x and y, $$1+x^2+2x\sin(\arccos y)=0$$
Firstly, if we take $z=\arccos(y)$ then $y=\cos(z)$ and so $\cos^2(z)=y^2$

we know that $\sin^2(z)+\cos^2(z)=1$ so

$1-\sin^2(z)=y^2\,\therefore \sin(z)=\sqrt{1-y^2}\therefore z=\arcsin(\sqrt{1-y^2})$

If we put this back into our original expression we get:
$$1+x^2+2x\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)\right)=0$$
so:
$$1+x^2+2x\sqrt{1-y^2}=0$$
this can be rearranged to give:
$$\sqrt{1-y^2}=-\frac{1+x^2}{2x}$$
This is the same as what you put, so it is correct so far. Now I would rearrange to:
$$y=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\right)^2}$$
For $y=0$,
$$\frac{1+x^2}{2x}=\pm1$$
solving this we get two equations, $x^2+2x+1=0$ and $x^2-2x+1=0$
these can be factorised to $(x+1)^2=0$ and $(x-1)^2=0$ giving the two clear solutions of $x=1$ and $x=-1$

So the answer is $x=\pm1$

Comment: What is the logic behind taking $y=0$?

Comment: We are trying to solve the equation which is the same as finding roots to it